# how to use SunVector input with this osl node?

Tags: osl

I recently downloaded an osl sky texture, but cannot work out how to make it work. It has a sunvector input on the node but I don't know how to use it. Any help is much appreciated.

https://bensimonds.com/2014/10/02/atmospheric-rendering-with-osl/